# I'm trying to insert columns before a cell that has specific text among a range of columns. The last cell will be non-empty. Is there a way to do it?

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I'm trying to insert columns before a cell that has specific text among a range of columns. The last cell will be non-empty. And then cut/paste a column onto the new column and delete the column from where the contents were cut using VBA. Is there a way without using Select/Activate function?

I recorded that part of macro but I don't know how to create a loop such that the macro is limited to the specified columns.

[This image is the example of columns which I want to get my desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o56jj.png)

I'm trying to achieve this:

1. Search cells with value "xyz"
2. Insert a column on the left of the cells found
3. Copy an entire column with a specific cell with value "abc" to newly inserted columns
4. Delete the columns after cut/paste

Here's the recorded part:

```
'Cells.Select
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("H:H").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("K:K").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("M:M").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("K:K").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("M:M").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("N:N").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("P:P").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("N:N").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("P:P").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("Q:Q").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("S:S").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("Q:Q").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("S:S").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("T:T").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("V:V").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("T:T").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("V:V").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("W:W").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("Y:Y").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("W:W").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("Y:Y").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("Z:Z").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("AB:AB").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("Z:Z").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("AB:AB").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("AC:AC").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("AE:AE").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("AC:AC").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("AE:AE").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("AF:AF").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("AH:AH").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("AF:AF").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("AH:AH").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("AI:AI").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("AK:AK").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("AI:AI").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("AK:AK").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("AL:AL").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("AN:AN").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("AL:AL").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("AN:AN").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Answer (score 0):

MoveXYZtoTheLeftOfABC will look for strings abc and xyz.  If they are both found it will move xyz EntireColumn to the right of abc's column.

**Usage:** `MoveXYZtoTheLeftOfABC "abc","xyz"`

Before
[image]

After
[image]

```
Sub MoveXYZtoTheLeftOfABC(abc As String, xyz As String)

    Dim rABC As Range, rXYZ As Range

    Set rABC = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=abc)

    If Not rABC Is Nothing Then
        Set rXYZ = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=xyz)
        If Not rXYZ Is Nothing Then
            rXYZ.EntireColumn.Cut
            rABC.EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! It works very well. However, I was wondering if it could somehow be looped? I have included on the OP a snippet of what I'm trying to achieve. I tried if condition to create a loop wherein the macro tries to find the specific text and then cut/paste columns but my excel stops responding.